# Load fxml file located in "src" maven folder

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am working on a JavaFX 8 (maven) project. I want to store an fxml file inside of sources (not inside resources) folder.
When I store my fxml to location /src/main/**resources**/views/b/MyFxml.fxml I am loading it without errors using the command,

```
new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/views/b/MyFxml.fxml"));
```

Is there any way to load my fxml file from  /src/main/**java**/package/name/RoleView.fxml location?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java does not make distinction between resources and sources. As long as your fxml file is visible in classpath (packaged into *.jar appropriately) you can reach it the same way. Given that you use maven, this is the configuration you need:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.fxml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Then, this line should work to load your file:

```
new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/package/name/RoleView.fxml"));
```

Comment: I didn't include this configuration for maven and my fxml was not included in the jar file. Thank you.